# Longest common prefix in binary representation

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, math, data-structures

We are given a undirected tree with `N (1 to N)` nodes rooted at node `1`. Every node has a value assigned with it,
represented by array - `A[i]` where `i:[1:N]`.

We need to answer **`Q`** queries of type :
-> **`V X`** : longest length of the common prefix between value `V` and any ancestor of node **`X`** including **`X`**, in their binary representation of 62-bit length.

**Common prefix** between 2 numbers is defined as:

Example :

```
4: 0..................0100 (62-bit binary representation)
6: 0..................0110 
Considering both as 62-bit in it's binary representation. 
Longest length of the common prefix is: 60 (as 60 left most bits are same.)
```

Now we are given the **N** (num nodes), **edges**, nodes values (**A[i]**) and **queries**, and we need to answer each query in optimal time.

**Constrains :**

```
N <= 10^5, number of nodes 
A[i] <= 10^9, value of each node
Q <= 10^5 ,number of queries
Edge[i] = (i, j) <= N
```

Approach :

1. Create tree and track the immediate parent of each node.
2. for Each Query : `[V, X]`, traverse each node `n`(in the path from **X to root**) and XOR each node's values with `V` and find the most significant set bit for each of the XOR operation and pick the minimum one among all of them.
3. So the result for Query : `[V, X]` : 62 - (1 + Step-2 result).

> Is there any other efficient way to solve this problem? As the above approach in worst case takes `O(n^2)` time.

Comment: Do you have any information about the shape of the tree?

Comment: Is there any relationship between X and the values of the ancestors of X?

Comment: @user3386109, there is no relationship given between X and the values of the ancestors of X, It's just an undirected tree with N nodes (each node can have any value from 1 to 10^9) having 1 as a root node.

Comment: One approach is to find the set bit from the left (MSB). For two numbers if they belong to range [2^(n-1), 2^n) then they will have same bit set from MSB, so at least the common prefix is till that bit, then few additional checks for subsequent bits. If they don't belong to same range then return the greater number's set MSB bit position - 1 as the common prefix. If you already know the tree (is not dynamically created), you can pre-compute this stuff and quickly return the results when queried.

Comment: Maintain a map of N bits and the list of numbers falling in the range [2^(n-1), 2^n) and when creating the tree (from inputs), add the values in the respective map key's list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem in O((N+Q) log N) time using [fully persistent binary search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure).

A "persistent" data structure is one that preserves the previous version when it's modified.  "Fully persistent" means that the previous versions can be modified as well.  Often, fully persistent data structures are implemented as [purely functional data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional_data_structure).

You need a binary search tree.  The classic example is [Okasaki's red-black trees](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150FP/archive/chris-okasaki/redblack99.pdf), but you could port any BST implementation from any purely functional language.

With this kind of data structure, your problem is easy to solve.

1. Create a singleton tree for the root that contains only the root value.
2. For each child, create a new version from its parent by adding the child's value.
3. Continue in BFS or DFS order until you have a version of the tree for every node that contains all of its ancestor's values.  This will require O(N log N) space and time all together.
4. For each query `[v,x]`, then, get the tree for node `x` and find the largest value `<= x`, and the smallest value `>= x`.  This takes O(log N) time.
5. The ancestor with the longest common prefix will be one of the the values you found.  Check them both by XORing them with `v` and choosing the smallest result.  Then binary search (or some faster bit-hack method) to find the position of the left-most bit.

---

NOTE: The above discussion assumes that you meant it when you said "we need to answer each query in optimal time".

If you can process the queries out of order, then you don't need persistent trees.  You can just use a single regular BST that you'd find in your language library, because you don't need all the trees at once.

Walk though the graph in pre-order, adjusting the tree for each node as you find it, and then process all the queries that specifically target that node.

Comment: I have not much idea about the persistent BSTs as of now, though in question it was not actually mentioned anywhere to answer the queries in online fashion, so I guess we could have answer it any order and then re-order it while returning the result[] array.

Comment: ok so for query (V, X), we need to find the largest value <= V, and the smallest value >= V, in the BST of nodes upto X nodes, which we are creating using preorder traversal.

Comment: Yes.  When you enter a node, you add its value to the tree, and when you leave a node, you remove its value.

Answer (score 2):

Java: use [numberOfLeadingZeros](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#numberOfLeadingZeros(long)). The classes Long and Integer have a nice set of utility functions.

```
long commonPrefix(long x, long y) {
    return Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(x ^ y);
}
```

On any algorithmic improvement: it would not be honest
to provide a superb solution here. And it is better
you work something out with pen and paper, puzzling the math side.
In fact I can see a tiny way. Maybe you can do even better.

Comment: I tried to solve it but couldn't figure how the time complexity can be reduced here with using maths, Could you describe your approach Or maybe give a hint of how to proceed.

Comment: Sorry, I simply have no time. I would need to program it too; just telling would be inferior to bad teaching. Consider the general pattern of bits in numbers with subtrees of 2-4-8-16 and so on. If you print in binary numbers you'll see the pattern and might utilize that. But first make a slow solution work,.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of a way which may be useful. You can modify the data in your node by adding an additional value for MSB bit set. For example, if number is 8, the MSB bit set, considering MSB is on left, is 62 - 4 = 58th bit from left. Also, you can store the bits in a **bitset**. So your tree node structure may be modified something like (in C++):

```
struct TreeNode
{
    int node_value;
    int set_msb_bit_from_left;
    bitset<62> b;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
};
```

Important points:

1. Two numbers, x and y, have same `set_msb_bit_from_left` if they fall in same range [2^(n-1), 2^n). So such numbers can be added into one group, say `Gi` where `i` is the value of `set_msb_bit_from_left`.
2. If x belongs to `Gi` and y belongs to `Gi+1`, longest common prefix is `i`.
3. If x belongs to `Gi` and y belongs to `Gj` and `i < j`, then longest common prefix is `i`.
4. If both x and y belong to same group, then bit-by-bit checking needs to be done starting from MSB to LSB until a mismatch is found, or some other efficient bit manipulation tricks like XOR operation.

Algorithm:

1. During creating nodes of tree, compute the `set_msb_bit_from_left` for the `node_value`.
2. <s>Create a data structure for storing groups based on `msb_bit_from_left`. This data structure can be a simple map or disjoint set union.</s>
3. For given two nodes V (nth-level child) and X (ancestor), put all nodes from X to V in a set with comparator based on increasing `set_msb_bit_from_left` or group id.
4. Go from last (highest group id) to first element (lowest group id) in the set and compute longest common prefix between x and y:

- Get group for x and y.
- If same, process from MSB to LSB until a mismatch is found or do XOR of all belonging to same group and return the output.
- Else, return `min(grp_id_x, grp_id_y) - 1` where `grp_id_x`, `grp_id_y` are the respective `set_msb_bit_from_left` values. `-1` because we don't wanna count set MSB bit.

NOTE: if there are two or more elements from the last which are in the same group, then you just need to find longest common prefix between them (no need to process elements from other group, the longest common prefix will be smaller).

Answer (score -1):

Find the length of binary representation of both numbers, if its not the same then there can't be any matching bits, so only leading zeroes are the common prefix. Otherwise we can find the XOR value to find the number of matching prefix bits.

It's a neat trick, because the XOR operation will turn all the matching bits to zero until the left most bit that doesn't match. So, length of the common prefix will be the difference between total length of binary representation of either number(since they're the same length) and the length of the XOR value's binary representation.

Finally, since you want it for 62 bits, you have add leading zeroes, the number of leading zeroes is 62 minus length of either number's binary representation.

So,
62 - length of either number + common prefix.
Further simplification would mean the answer is 62 - length of xor value;

The only tricky case here if the numbers are same, you can handle that upfront.

```
int commonPrefix(int x, int y)
    if(x == y)
        return 62;

    int xLength = Math.floor(Math.log(x) + 1);
    int yLength = Math.floor(Math.log(x) + 1);
    
    if(xLength != yLength)
        return 62 - Math.max(xLength, yLength);

    int xor = x ^ y;
    int xorLength = Math.floor(Math.log(xor) + 1);

    return 62 - xorLength;
```

Once you've got that covered a simple DFS should give you the ancestors of the node you're looking for and you can find the longest common prefix by comparing the given value with every ancestor.

Comment: This approach would be ```O(n^2)``` in worst case, I am looking for more efficient approach here, as brute force is quite slow.